# Equation always evaluates to 0, even when it shouldn't

Tags: java, opengl

I'm trying to use lwjgl to render a textured rectangle onto the screen. I have already registered the textures and loaded them. I'm trying to write a method that will use only a specified area of the texture to apply to the rectangle, this will then allow the use of spritesheets. I have this code to do it:

```
public static void drawTexturedRectangle(int x, int y, int width,
        int height, int textureX, int textureY, int textureWidth,
        int textureHeight, Texture texture) {

    System.out.println("Drawing tr:"); //console output to check input
    System.out.println("  -input:");
    System.out.println("    -x: " + x);
    System.out.println("    -y: " + y);
    System.out.println("    -width: " + width);
    System.out.println("    -height: " + height);
    System.out.println("    -tex-x: " + textureX);
    System.out.println("    -tex-y: " + textureY);
    System.out.println("    -tex-width: " + textureWidth);
    System.out.println("    -tex-height: " + textureHeight);

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getId());
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    {

        System.out.println("  -rendered:");

        int vx = x; // define the x-coordinate for the first vertex
        int vy = y+height; // define the x-coordinate for the first vertex
        float tx = (1 / texture.getWidth()) * textureX; // define the x-coordinate of the texture section
        float ty = (1 / texture.getHeight()) * textureY;// define the y-coordinate of the texture section
        System.out.println("    -point 1:"); // more system output
        System.out.println("      -x: " + vx);
        System.out.println("      -y: " + vy);
        System.out.println("      -tex-x: " + tx); // these are always 0.0
        System.out.println("      -tex-y: " + ty); // ^^ even if textureY = texture.getHeight() which should evaluate to 1
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(tx, ty); // Actually carry out the opengl commands.
        GL11.glVertex2i(vx, vy); // ^^

        // Repeat above
        vx = x;
        vy = y;
        tx = (1 / texture.getWidth()) * textureX;
        ty = (1 / texture.getHeight()) * (textureY + textureHeight);
        System.out.println("    -point 2:");
        System.out.println("      -x: " + vx);
        System.out.println("      -y: " + vy);
        System.out.println("      -tex-x: " + tx);
        System.out.println("      -tex-y: " + ty);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(tx,ty);
        GL11.glVertex2i(vx, vy);

        // Repeat again
        vx = x+width;
        vy = y;
        tx = (1 / texture.getWidth()) * (textureX + textureWidth);
        ty = (1 / texture.getHeight()) * (textureY - textureHeight);
        System.out.println("    -point 3:");
        System.out.println("      -x: " + vx);
        System.out.println("      -y: " + vy);
        System.out.println("      -tex-x: " + tx);
        System.out.println("      -tex-y: " + ty);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(tx,ty);
        GL11.glVertex2i(vx, vy);

        //One more time to make a quad!
        vx = x+width;
        vy = y+height;
        tx = (1 / texture.getWidth()) * (textureX + textureWidth);
        ty = (1 / texture.getHeight()) * textureY;
        System.out.println("    -point 4:");
        System.out.println("      -x: " + vx);
        System.out.println("      -y: " + vy);
        System.out.println("      -tex-x: " + tx);
        System.out.println("      -tex-y: " + ty);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(tx,ty);
        GL11.glVertex2i(vx, vy);
    }
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

However, when run the values for tx an ty are always evaluated to 0.0.

Texture is a class which stores the registered id and pixel width and height of the texture.

x, y, width and height are the respective properties of the rectangle.

"textureX" and "textureY" are the coordinates of the top left of the image on the texture (I know bottom left is opengl standard)

"textureWidth" and "textureHeight" are the width and height of the section of the texture.

Answer (score 5):

This is your problem:

```
float tx = (1 / texture.getWidth()) * textureX;
```

Texture is an integer, and when you divide integers you get an interger. Everything past the ones digit is truncated. This expression evaluates zero.

You can fix this by making one a floating point number:

```
float tx = (1f / texture.getWidth()) * textureX;
```

Or a double for more precision:

```
float tx = (float)(1.0 / texture.getWidth()) * textureX;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to make `1` a `double` and cast to `float` as the last operation to keep more precision?

Comment: @user3580294 Yeah sure, but you have to make an extra cast. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you're doing int division, which will truncate any decimals.

Let's take this for example:

```
float tx = (1 / texture.getWidth()) * textureX;
```

Let's say that texture.getWidth() returns 100. 1/100 is .01, but since an int divided by an int is an int, that is truncated to 0. You then multiply 0 by textureX, which obviously evaluates to 0.

The solution is to cast the value returned from getWidth() to a float, or to just use 1.0 or 1f instead of the int literal 1.